# How to search/filter emails in Gmail according to recipients

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-search

I know this tutorial: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190

But when I use the `TO:` operator (`TO:myemail@myemail.com`), I get also emails where is used `myemail@myemail.com` for CC or BCC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `TO:myemail@myemail.com` will return all messages sent to myemail@myemail.com, including those where myemail@myemail.com is CCed (or BCCed in case you send the e-mail, since you can see the BCC).

Use `TO:myemail@myemail.com -CC:myemail@myemail.com -BCC:myemail@myemail.com` instead. (the 'not' function is represented by a minus `-`)

Parenthesis are only required when you want to search for two or more email addresses for that operator, i.e., `TO:(myemail@myemail.com OR myotheremail@email.com)`

Comment: The parenthesis are only required when there are more than on email address for the operator.